# Maven: how to invoke a plugin with execution specific config

Tags: maven, plugins

I have written a plugin and want to treat the goal vrs (check versions) differently,
depending on execution/command line.

In my code I added

```
   @Parameter(name = "versionsWarnOnly", defaultValue = "true")
    private boolean versionsWarnOnly;

    public boolean getVersionsWarnOnly() {
    System.out.println("invoked get");
    return this.versionsWarnOnly;
    }

    public void setVersionsWarnOnly(boolean versionsWarnOnly) {
    System.out.println("invoked set");
    this.versionsWarnOnly = versionsWarnOnly;
    }
```

I would expect, that without specifying versionsWarnOnly in the configuration in the pom, i just get the defaultValue specified.

The problem is, that does not happen, it is always false in that case.

If i configure in the configuration
of the plugin in the pom

```
<versionsWarnOnly>true</versionsWarnOnly>
```

Then this is done (well some success) if I build the phase `mvn validate`.
It is even true if I invoke the goal from the command line by goal `mvn latex:vrs`.

But if i specify that in an execution that like,

```
      <execution>
        <id>validate_converters</id>
        <phase>validate</phase>
        <configuration>
          <versionsWarnOnly>true</versionsWarnOnly>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
              <goal>vrs</goal>
            </goals>
      </execution>
```

again it has no effect.
I have no idea what i do wrong
or what kind of information you need to help me.

Comment: Please take a deep look into https://blog.soebes.de/blog/2021/04/05/maven-plugin-configuration/

Comment: Update: ```@Parameter(name = "versionsWarnOnly", defaultValue = "xxx")
    private String versionsWarnOnly = "yyy";``` shows that defaultValue does not work but direct assignment does work.

Comment: The injection is not done via setter/getter...so better use the `execute()` method and printout the values there...apart from that without the full code it's hard so see if/where an issue might be...

Comment: @khmarbaise.. a good blog indeed... Well I did some printout in execute. Thats how i received my results. 

But what do you mean by 'injection is not done via getter/setter?

Comment: The getter and setters are not used for parameter injection...it's done by attribute injection...

Comment: @khmarbaise: i could offer you the full code, no problem. in which form I can send?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is resolved and the question could be deleted altogether.
The problem was that I put almost all of the config into a class Settings.
On the other hand, I added the new parameter outside and so it had no effect.
Thats all.
Now all works fine.